# SimpleDB - Duplicating tables, or being able to create a separate dev account?

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I'm just wondering what's the standard practice for setting up a separate environment for development to production with domains (/ tables) in Amazon's Simple DB?

I assume that it could be possible to either:

- Duplicate the domain/table, and handle the switching in my data access library.

  - *If so - how do I best script the table re-creation?*
    .
- Or, create a second Access Key, and switch the connection string appropriately

  - *If so, where can this be done in the AWS portal?* I haven't been able to find any hints that it could be done...

Any comments on what the common practice is, is of course appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a different region for development and production.  From the AWS console, set up 2 different IAMs accounts and assign a user policy like the following.

{
  "Statement": [{
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":["sdb:*"],
        "Resource":"arn:aws:sdb:us-west-2:REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ACCOUNTID:domain/*"
     }]
}

By default an IAMs account is denied access.  The above policy makes the IAM user a SimpleDB admin within the us-west-2 region.  Each IAM account will have a key and secret from AWS.  Switch IDs according to your environment.  A Google search showed me multiple SDB backup solutions and I assume some will probably allow you to backup from one AWS region and restore to another.